# Drag drop multiselect option

Tags: jquery, html

Dropdown code..
        
     Available items
      @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.Fields.Count; i++) { @ViewBag.Fields[i].Name }  
     
     
    Selected items

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@sort1, #@sort2").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: <div class="availableContainer">
    <span style="font-weight: bold">Available items</span>
    <select name="@sort1" id="@sort1" multiple="multiple" class="connectedSortable">
        @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            <option value="@ViewBag.Fields[i].Name">@ViewBag.Fields[i].Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="selectedContainer">
    <span style="font-weight: bold">Selected items</span>
    <select name="@sort2" id="@sort2" multiple="multiple" class="connectedSortable">            
    </select>
</div>

Comment: this is drop down  html code

Comment: @NarenderChoudhary Update the question, don't add code in comments

Comment: I want to drag drop multiselect(dropdown) option using jquery

Comment: Why are you using `@` with `@sor..`? Looks like you are using ASP.Net MVC

Comment: @ Tushar  
I want to drag drop multiselect(dropdown) option  with each other using jquery

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Multi-Select-List-Box-fieldChooser/demo/  ..like this but these are div drtag drop i want to drag drop dropdown optons...

Answer (score 0):

Try to escaping the special characters use `'\\'`

```
$("#\\@sort1, #\\@sort2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
 }).disableSelection();
```

For reference : [**Stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)